# Unable to find ng command for ionic v4 but otherwise ok when using ionic v6

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm, volta

I am on a Windows machine using Volta to manage different versions of node.

I have 2 different ionic apps in 2 different folders with 2 different versions of ionic.

In 1 folder, I am able to run `ionic serve` and the app is served in the browser. In this folder, these are my values.

```
npm --version
6.14.11

node --version
v14.15.5

ionic --version
6.13.1

ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 11.2.6
Node: 14.15.5
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.7
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.6
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.6
@angular/cli                    11.2.6
@schematics/angular             11.2.6
@schematics/update              0.1102.6
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.0.7
```

These are the gcm values for the commands:

```
gcm ionic

CommandType     Name             Version    Source
-----------     ----             -------    ------
Application     ionic.exe        0.0.0.0    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Volta\bin\ionic.exe

gcm npm

CommandType     Name             Version    Source
-----------     ----             -------    ------
Application     npm.exe        0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\Volta\npm.exe

gcm node

CommandType     Name             Version    Source
-----------     ----             -------    ------
Application     node.exe        0.0.0.0    C:\Program Files\Volta\node.exe

gcm ng

CommandType     Name             Version    Source
-----------     ----             -------    ------
Application     ng.exe        0.0.0.0    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Volta\bin\ng.exe
```

But in the other folder, my ionic command can't seem to find `ng`. And this is what I get when I use `ionic serve`

`` [ng] Volta error: Could not locate executable `ng` in your project. ``

These are my values:

```
npm --version
6.14.11

node --version
v14.15.5

ionic --version
4.12.0

ng --version
Volta error: Could not locate executable `ng` in your project.
```

What might be missing here?

```
gcm ionic

CommandType     Name               Version    Source
-----------     ----               -------    ------
Application     ionic.exe          0.0.0.0    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Volta\bin\ionic.exe

gcm ng

CommandType     Name               Version    Source
-----------     ----               -------    ------
Application     ng.exe             0.0.0.0    C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Volta\bin\ng.exe
```

What might be the issue here that is blocking the ionic v4 from finding the ng executable?

Comment: Thinking about this, so the second folder might be using the ionic in the node_modules and. That ionic command fails to get the ng executable. Sounds logic right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the project was on an exFAT disk. Moving the project to an NTFS disk and running install again works. The issue is no longer reproducible on an NTFS disk.